# how to drag n drop with the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Drag & hhkhhDrop </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Style.css" />


 
</head>


<body>

<h3>Moving words around to make a sentence</h3>
<div id="answerDiv">
 
     <div class="dragDropSmallBox" class="destinationBox"   id="a6">Page</div>
  <div class="dragDropSmallBox" class="destinationBox"   id="a1">THIS</div>
  <div class="dragDropSmallBox" class="destinationBox"   id="a5">Web</div>
  <div class="dragDropSmallBox" class="destinationBox"   id="a2">Is</div>
  <div class="dragDropSmallBox" class="destinationBox"   id="a4">Nice</div>
  <div class="dragDropSmallBox" class="destinationBox"   id="a3">A</div>
  
  
 </div>

<div style="padding-top:280px;">
 <div id="questionDiv">
  
  <div class="mover" class="dragDropSmallBox" id="q1">1</div>
  <div class="destinationBox"></div>
  <div class="mover" class="dragDropSmallBox" id="q2">2</div>
  <div class="destinationBox"></div>
  <div class="mover" class="dragDropSmallBox" id="q3">3</div>
  <div class="destinationBox"></div>
  <div class="mover" class="dragDropSmallBox" id="q4">4</div>
  <div class="destinationBox"></div>
  <div class="mover" class="dragDropSmallBox" id="q5">5</div>
  <div class="destinationBox"></div>
  <div class="mover" class="dragDropSmallBox" id="q6">6</div>
  <div class="destinationBox"></div>
  
 
 
 </div>

 
 
 </div>
 
<div id="dragContent"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="dragDropResetForm();return false"  class="reset" value="Reset">
</body>
</html>
```

I already have a drag and drop function for the elements in the page , but i want to make the elements draggable with a separate click to drop , that means i want to click on the mouse to drag the element and another click to drop it where it suppose to be dropped . any help please ?

Comment: Can you either add a working fiddle or down size all this code to only what the question is asking?

Comment: i've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

JQueryUI has a nice inbuilt method called draggable. It allows you to drag and move different elements on the page.

Read more about it here: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple, yet elegant solution. Here you have to make additional click to drop the element.

```
var dragContentDiv = document.getElementById('dragContent');

// Disable browser's drag and drop functionality
dragContentDiv.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};

// Watch the mouse button press
dragContentDiv.onmousedown = function(e) {
  // Move the selected element to absolute coordinates
  dragContentDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
  moveAt(e);
  // If needed, move element to the body, so it's not inside of position:relative block
  document.body.appendChild(dragContentDiv);

  // Show dragContentDiv above all other elements
  dragContentDiv.style.zIndex = 1000; // показывать мяч над другими элементами

  // Move element horisontally under cursor coordinates
  // and move it halfway of it's width to make it centered
  function moveAt(e) {
    dragContentDiv.style.left = e.pageX - dragContentDiv.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
  }

  // Move it around the screen
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    moveAt(e);
  }

  // Watch the end of a process
  dragContentDiv.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    dragContentDiv.onmouseup = null;
  }
}
```